# A step in deriving the solution to heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, leibniz-integral-rule

I'm trying to understand how to solve the heat equation. I'm stuck on this particular step:

$$Q(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-s^2}ds, t > 0.$$

I want to compute $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}.$ This should turn out to be
$$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt {4k\pi}t}e^{-\dfrac{x^2}{4kt}}.$$ I think we have to use Leibniz integral rule but not sure how to do it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never forget the fundamental theorem of calculus!
$$\mathrm{\partial}_x\left[\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(s)\mathrm{d}s\right]=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$$
So in your example,
$$\partial_x Q(x,t)=\partial_x\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_0^{x/\sqrt{4 kt}}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm{d}s\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4kt}\right)$$

Comment: I am slightly confused between FTOC and Leibniz integral rule which is as follows: $$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt\bigg)  = f(x,b(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}b(x) - f(x,a(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)dt.$$ Do you mind elaborating why we have this extra term in the Leibniz rule and why it is not valid here ?

Comment: The reason the result is so simple in this case is because the integrand doesn't have any $x$ in it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$H(x,t) = Q(x\sqrt{4kt},t) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_0^x e^{-s^2}ds $$

So $$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2} $$ by Leibnitz or just plain differentiation under the integral sign.

Can you finish from this point on?

Comment: just a question how can we apply Leibniz here. I posed a similar question to the above answer. Do you mind elaborating on the technicalities?